# Kafka connect get secret from file with variable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Im planning to use the Kafka external secret via variable. Basically I want to pass the password field from a file. But that file doesn't contain the password, instrad it'll call a command and get the password. Here is my example file.

```
pass=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value \
--secret-id dev/debezium/mysql/testservice/password \
--region ap-south-1)
```

In my connector config has this line.

```
"database.password": "${file:/etc/kafka/mysql-secret.properties:pass}",
```

But it seems, its not working for me. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `"database.password": "${file:/etc/kafka/mysql-secret.properties:pass}",`

This will simply read the value from the file specified. It won't execute it.

Kafka Connect does support [externalised password providers](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-297%3A+Externalizing+Secrets+for+Connect+Configurations). I found [this](https://docs.lenses.io/4.0/integrations/connectors/secret-providers/) which looks like one option for implementing that with AWS secretsmanager.